Find a point on the ellipse $x^2/4 + y^2 = 1$ that lies the closest to the line y = 4-x
This is the question that was on my exam and now i know that it can be solved by taking a random point (x,y), taking the distance from it to the line and then making a function $$F(x,y,z) = (distance) - z(x^2/4 + y^2 - 1) $$of which you find the minimum of. This is an obvious way now to me, but on the exam i didnt notice it and i chose a random point on the line so $(x_1, 4-x_1)$ and a random point on the ellipse so $(x_2, \sqrt(1-x_2/4))$. I took the positive one because its obvious from drawing these two that the closest point is gonna be when y is positive. But this got me nowhere basically i got really ugly derivatives of which i couldnt find the zeros of. My question is, could i have solved this or would i have to use the first method?

Write tangent paralell to given line. So it is $y=-x+n$ and then solve $$x^2+4(n-x)^2=4$$ on $x$. It has $0$  discriminant, so you'l get $n$ and then you can calculate the point on ellipse closest to line $y=-x+4$.

Why should we calculate $n$? Can't we use the general eqn of tangent for an ellipse?

@MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad  Probably

We need to find the smallest distance $(2\cos t,\sin t)$ from $$x+y-4=0$$
the distance =
$$\dfrac{|2\cos t+\sin t-4|}{\sqrt{1^2+1^2}}$$
Now  $4-\sqrt5\le|2\cos t+\sin t-4|\le4+\le\sqrt5$
the left equality occurs if $2\cos t+\sin t=\sqrt5\iff\sin\left(t+\arcsin\dfrac2{\sqrt5}\right)=0$
$\iff t+\arcsin\dfrac2{\sqrt5}=n\pi, 0\le n\le1$
